# In Edit method, updating data create new data instead mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

This is my Controllers Edit Method in Httpost

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Employee employee)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var department = db.Departments.ToList();
            var viewModel = new EmployeeViewModel
            {
                Departments = department,
                Employees = db.Employees.ToList()
            };
            return View("Index", viewModel);
        }

        db.Entry(employee).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

this method creates new data instead of updating data.

Comment: Does `employee` contain the correct identifier for the existing record?

Comment: correct identifier means?

Comment: The ID for the record.  What is your `Employee` class definition?  When you debug, what specific values are in the `employee` variable?

Comment: This is my Employee 
`public partial class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Departments")]
        public int Department_Id { get; set; }
    
        public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    }`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're trying to update `Employee` instance directly based from action parameter without seeking any matching record first, hence EF "unaware" if the entity should be modified and treat its state as `EntityState.Added` in this line:

```
db.Entry(employee).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

What you should do is using `SingleOrDefault()` or `FirstOrDefault()` to fetch matching record based from `Id` property, update all required properties then attach `Employee` instance into `Employees` entity and set its state as `EntityState.Modified`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Employee employee)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var department = db.Departments.ToList();
        var viewModel = new EmployeeViewModel
        {
            Departments = department,
            Employees = db.Employees.ToList()
        };
        return View("Index", viewModel);
    }

    // find employee with matching ID first
    var selectedEmployee = db.Employees.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == employee.Id);

    // update all properties
    selectedEmployee.Name = employee.Name;
    // other properties here

    // attach the context
    db.Employees.Attach(selectedEmployee); 

    // set modified state and save all changes
    db.Entry(selectedEmployee).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Related issues:

[Why does Entity Framework reinsert existing objects into my database?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx)

[Updating the Record with EntityState.Modified but its inserting the new row rather than update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35110965/updating-the-record-with-entitystate-modified-but-its-inserting-the-new-row-rath)